# Pilatus PC-12 vertical tail size

Tags: flight-controls, tail, vertical-stabilizer, pilatus-pc-12

Does anyone know what the dimensions / surface area of the vertical stabilizer is on that plane? Additionally, does anyone know the approximate tail volume and its coefficient?

Could not find it anywhere on the internet.

I do not need exact figures (although it would be better), educated guesses or approximations are enough.

Comment: You could get a rough estimate from a scale drawing.

Comment: Or by measuring a picture in profile. Finding the overall length should be easy enough, so from that you'll have the scale of the picture you find.